# C++ CLI lambda expression with handle to managed object

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to convert he following C# code to C++/CLI

```cs
// create the output bitmap
var bitmap = new SKBitmap();
SKImageInfo info = new SKImageInfo();
info = new SKImageInfo(input.Width, input.Height, SKColorType.Bgra8888);

// create the buffer that will hold the pixels
var buffer = new byte[input.Width * input.Height * 4];

// get a pointer to the buffer, and give it to the bitmap
var outputPtr = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
bitmap.InstallPixels(info, outputPtr.AddrOfPinnedObject(), info.RowBytes, (addr, ctx) => outputPtr.Free(), null);
```

I've tried different options and but I keep getting stuck. I now have this:

```cpp
static void FreeHandle(System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle handle) 
{
    handle.Free();
}

static void Test()
{
    // create the output bitmap
    SKBitmap^ bitmap = gcnew SKBitmap();
    SKImageInfo^ info = gcnew SKImageInfo(input.cols, input.rows, SKColorType::Bgra8888);

    // Create a buffer, pin it and give its pointer to the bitmap
    array<System::Byte>^ buffer = gcnew array<System::Byte>(input.cols * input.rows * 4);
    GCHandle outputPtr = GCHandle::Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType::Pinned);

    bitmap->InstallPixels(info, outputPtr.AddrOfPinnedObject(), info->RowBytes, gcnew Action<GCHandle>(outputPtr, &FreeHandle), nullptr);
}
```

This gives me the error

> invalid delegate initializer -- object is not needed for the specified function.

I also tried:

```cpp
// create the output bitmap
SKBitmap^ bitmap = gcnew SKBitmap();
SKImageInfo^ info = gcnew SKImageInfo(input.cols, input.rows, SKColorType::Bgra8888);

// Create a buffer, pin it and give its pointer to the bitmap
array<System::Byte>^ buffer = gcnew array<System::Byte>(input.cols * input.rows * 4);

gcroot<GCHandle> outputPtr = GCHandle::Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType::Pinned);
bitmap->InstallPixels(info, outputPtr.AddrOfPinnedObject(), info->RowBytes, [&]() -> void { outputPtr->Free(); }, nullptr);
```

but then I get:

> expression must have pointer or handle type but it has type "System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle".

I searched a lot, but I'm not sure how to search this anymore.

Comment: No support for lambda expressions, that hurts here.  You'll have to hack it with gcnew SKBitmapReleaseDelegate(nullptr, &FreeHandle) and store outputPtr in a static field of the class so FreeHandle() can retrieve it.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah I see, I was afraid of that already. In this case that would be very difficult to do since the CLI class is static, but there can be multiple instances of the SKBitmap that I want to keep the handle of. Then I would have to keep them in a list or something which would make the code very confusing.

Comment: That's what the SKBitmapReleaseDelegate's *context* argument can help you with.  Instead of nullptr you can pass outputPtr.ToIntPtr() as the last parameter of InstallPixels().  In FreeHandle() you can use GCHandle::FromIntPtr() to recover the GCHandle.